# Negative margin produce transparent Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This DIV slide its contents to the window.scroll:

```
<div style="overflow:visible">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<b>hello</b>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var div = $('div');
      var diff = $(window).scrollTop() - div.offset().top;
      if (diff <= 0) diff=0;
      div.css({marginTop:diff,marginBottom:-diff});

    });
  });
</script>
```

If i scroll down, the `hi`stands right behind `hello`.

How to force a white background?

@kitty
This is my Fiddle-Screen
[image]

Comment: use the fiddle of kitty

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fiddle your case and [thats](http://jsfiddle.net/nMu5N/) what happened.

You can use css rule `background-color: white` to do what you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nMu5N/1/)

Comment: Ah, ok sorry. Both have the problem. `hi` still has a transparent background. Please give a Screenshot.

Comment: This screenshot proof nothing. `hi` is invisible, scroll to `hi` and make a Screenshot.